# Can not send mail using yahoo in java

Tags: java

Error:

DEBUG: setDebug: JavaMail version 1.4ea
    DEBUG: getProvider() returning javax.mail.Provider[TRANSPORT,smtp,com.sun.mail.smtp.SMTPTransport,Sun Microsystems, Inc]
    DEBUG SMTP: useEhlo true, useAuth true
    DEBUG SMTP: trying to connect to host "smtp.mail.yahoo.com", port 465, isSSL false
    javax.mail.MessagingException: Could not connect to SMTP host: smtp.mail.yahoo.com, port: 465;
      nested exception is:
        java.net.ConnectException: Connection timed out: connect
    253  ******@yahoo.com test ******@yahoo.com Dear

```
    at com.sun.mail.smtp.SMTPTransport.openServer(SMTPTransport.java:1282)
    at com.sun.mail.smtp.SMTPTransport.protocolConnect(SMTPTransport.java:370)
    at javax.mail.Service.connect(Service.java:275)
    at javax.mail.Service.connect(Service.java:156)
    at SendEmail.sendFromYahoo(SendEmail.java:137)
    at SendEmail.main(SendEmail.java:50)
Caused by: java.net.ConnectException: Connection timed out: connect
    at java.net.DualStackPlainSocketImpl.connect0(Native Method)
    at java.net.DualStackPlainSocketImpl.socketConnect(DualStackPlainSocketImpl.java:79)
    at java.net.AbstractPlainSocketImpl.doConnect(AbstractPlainSocketImpl.java:339)
    at java.net.AbstractPlainSocketImpl.connectToAddress(AbstractPlainSocketImpl.java:200)
    at java.net.AbstractPlainSocketImpl.connect(AbstractPlainSocketImpl.java:182)
    at java.net.PlainSocketImpl.connect(PlainSocketImpl.java:172)
    at java.net.SocksSocketImpl.connect(SocksSocketImpl.java:392)
    at java.net.Socket.connect(Socket.java:579)
    at java.net.Socket.connect(Socket.java:528)
    at com.sun.mail.util.SocketFetcher.createSocket(SocketFetcher.java:232)
    at com.sun.mail.util.SocketFetcher.getSocket(SocketFetcher.java:189)
    at com.sun.mail.smtp.SMTPTransport.openServer(SMTPTransport.java:1250)
    ... 5 more
```

i want to send mail using yahoo mail in java
My code is

```
Properties props = System.getProperties();
        String host = "smtp.mail.yahoo.com";
        props.put("mail.smtp.starttls.enable", "true");
        props.put("mail.smtp.host", host);
        props.put("mail.smtp.user", from);
        props.put("mail.smtp.password", pass);
        props.put("mail.smtp.ssl.enable", "true");
        props.put("mail.smtp.port", "465");//587
        props.put("mail.smtp.auth", "true");

        Session session = Session.getDefaultInstance(props);
        MimeMessage message = new MimeMessage(session);
        session.setDebug(true);

        try {
            message.setFrom(new InternetAddress(from));
            InternetAddress[] toAddress = new InternetAddress[to.length];

            // To get the array of addresses
            for( int i = 0; i < to.length; i++ ) {
                toAddress[i] = new InternetAddress(to[i]);
            }

            for( int i = 0; i < toAddress.length; i++) {
                message.addRecipient(Message.RecipientType.TO, toAddress[i]);
            }

            message.setSubject(subject);
            message.setText(body);
            Transport transport = session.getTransport("smtp");
            transport.connect(host, from, pass);
            transport.sendMessage(message, message.getAllRecipients());
            transport.close();
            System.out.println("Sent message successfully....");
        }
        catch (AddressException ae) {
            ae.printStackTrace();
        }
        catch (MessagingException me) {
            me.printStackTrace();
        }
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should be able to send an email using the following program:

```
public class SendMail {
    String host, port, emailid,username, password;
    Properties props = System.getProperties();
    Session l_session = null;

    public SendMail() {
        host = "smtp.mail.yahoo.com";
        port = "465";
        emailid = "...@yahoo.com";
        username = "...";
        password = "pwd";

        emailSettings();
        createSession();
        sendMessage("...@yahoo.com", "xyz@gmail.com","Test subject","Test mail with some random text");
    }

    public void emailSettings() {
        props.put("mail.smtp.host", host);
        props.put("mail.smtp.auth", "true");
        props.put("mail.debug", "false");
        props.put("mail.smtp.port", port);
    }

    public void createSession() {
        l_session = Session.getInstance(props,
                new javax.mail.Authenticator() {
                    protected PasswordAuthentication getPasswordAuthentication() {
                        return new PasswordAuthentication(username, password);
                    }
                });
        l_session.setDebug(true);
    }

    public boolean sendMessage(String emailFromUser, String toEmail, String subject, String messageText) {
        try {
            MimeMessage message = new MimeMessage(l_session);
            emailid = emailFromUser;
            message.setFrom(new InternetAddress(this.emailid));

            message.addRecipient(Message.RecipientType.TO, new InternetAddress(toEmail));
            message.addRecipient(Message.RecipientType.BCC, new InternetAddress(toEmail));
            message.setSubject(subject);
            message.setContent(messageText, "text/html");

            Transport.send(message);
            System.out.println("An email has been sent");
        } catch (MessagingException mex) {
            mex.printStackTrace();
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        return true;
    }
}
```

Hope this helps!

Comment: Thanks for replay... but Now my previous code is working...
 it was a network related problem. Firewall was blocking this request.

Comment: That's cool, if my answer helps in any way - please do accept and upvote, else it's fine!